# I need to store the XML in SERVER through PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I need to store the XML that i get it from Google Analytics. Its format is XML file. I need to create the script ( PHP ) that will read XML file from Google Analytics and store in my server with user defined name. I tried like that

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/export?fmt=1&id=346044461&pdr=20100611-20100711&cmp=average&rpt=DashboardReport');
$dom->save('books3.xml');
?>
```

Can you help me

Comment: What happened when you tried your code out? I would guess it doesn't work because your script isn't authenticated. You'll need to use Google's analytics API or spoof a login.

Answer (score 0):

you're not assigning the result of `load` to anything you can save afterwards. and that is assuming you created a function `load`.

you'd need something more along the lines of

```
<?php
$remoteUri = 'https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/export?...';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents($remoteUri));
$xml = $doc->saveXML($doc->documentElement);
file_put_contents($yourLocalFilePath, $xml);
```

or if you just want a completely verbatim copy locally:

```
<?php
$remoteUri = ...

file_put_contents($yourLocalFilePath, file_get_contents($remoteUri));
```

the second, simpler version doesn't attempt to parse any xml and will therefore not have any clue if something is wrong with the recieved document.

depending on your server, you might have to resort to more complex methods of getting the file if url wrappers for `fopen` aren't enabled, or if your google endpoint wants to use cookies etc. for example.